# How to download APK from Emulator to Desktop

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-install-apk

I want to download Running APK from emulator to my computer. 
Somehow i missed that version and want to download from device. Is there any way to download ADB from devices.

Answer (score 6):

Do the following

- Use `adb shell pm list packages` to get the list of installed packages
- Find the desired package
- Get the actual file name and location of the APK using `adb shell pm path your-package-name`.
- Pull the apk using `adb pull full/directory/of/the.apk`

Answer (score 3):

**1. First of all let’s plug our smartphone to the USB port of our computer and get a list of the installed packages and their namespaces:**

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

**2. This will list all packages on your smartphone, once you’ve found the namespace of the package you want to reverse** (`com.android.systemui in` this example), **let’s see what its physical path is:**

```
adb shell pm path com.android.systemui
```

**3. Finally, we have the APK path:**

```
package:/system/priv-app/SystemUIGoogle/SystemUIGoogle.apk
```

**4. Let’s pull it from the device:**

```
adb pull /system/priv-app/SystemUIGoogle/SystemUIGoogle.apk
```

=====> And here you go, you have the APK!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your Answers. Finally i solved this problem and like to share with you. The steps to Download APK from Emulator to Desktop are given as follows ...

```
1. check the package list
adb shell pm list packages
adb shell pm list packages -f -3

2. find actual path
adb shell pm path [your_package_path]
Example: adb shell pm path com.android.certinstaller

3. output should look like
{your_path}/[your_apk].apk
Example: system/app/CertInstaller/CertInstaller.apk

4. actual execution command
adb pull /data/app/[your_package_name]-1/[your_apk].apk [local download path]
Example: adb pull /data/app/io.crash.air-1/base.apk /Documents/APK/
```